# Kibana throws an error upon launch through cmd

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, kibana

I've just installed Elasticsearch and Kibana's latest versions (same versions) on Windows. When I launch Elasticsearch it starts just as normal and I can check through the browser that it's on the required port. But when I launch Kibana it gives me the error "\config was unexpected". I checked the configurations and made sure that Kibana knew where to connect to ES and tried re-installs but nothing changed. When I tried it on an Ubuntu virtual machine the two worked normally. I don't know where the issue is. Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Pls post complete error message

Comment: I added the bin directory to PATH and typed "kibana.bat" in cmd just as with ES (which works normally and I can interact with it over curl) and an error comes up saying "\kibana-7.10-windows-x86_64\config was unexpected" and that's it nothing happens afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I'll just leave this for future reference:

1. Some people solved this by downgrading their Java: I did the same thing going from Java 15 to Java 8 but it didn't solve the issue for me. But still something to try.
2. What solved this for me was simply to change the path of the Kibana directory. Apparently Windows had some trouble reading its own default name for the parent directory. Moving the kibana folder to a simpler directory (like C:) and even renaming the folder to simply "kibana" instead of including the version etc. made it run as normal.